# Solve: $x$, $y$ are real, and $(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2=6$, find the maximum value of $\frac{y+1}{x+2}$

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

Solve: $x$, $y$ are real, and $(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2=6$, find the maximum value of $\frac{y+1}{x+2}$

This question is from a class I'm taking, and the current topic is discriminants. I found the discriminant of the equation in x and y to find the maximum and minimum values of x and y that yield real solutions for $(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2=6$, but I can't figure out how to maximize $\frac{y+1}{x+2}$ because if I maximize x, I don't know whether y is minimized. Hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**
Set $\frac{y+1}{x+2}=k$. The problem then asks for the maximum value of $k$.

You have 
$$(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2=6 \\
y=k(x+2)-1$$
Replacing in the first equation you get
$$
(x-3)^2+\bigl(k(x+2)-1-3\bigr)^2=6
$$

This is a quadratic equation for $x$, and if you think for a moment, you should realize that the problem is equivalent to: Find the largest $k$ for which this equation has a real solution.

Comment: @NoChance Why do you think you need to consider integers only? Nothing in the problem or the hint refers to integers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I miss read your last line.

Comment: @NoChance No problem. If the choice of $k$ for the parameter lead to this confusion, you can use a different letter :)

Comment: Not at all it is just that I was thinking of something else....Thanks again.

Comment: I simplified the expression and took the discriminant, but I ended up with $64k^2-20k-40$ in the discriminant... did I just do something wrong or is the answer actually infinity?

Comment: @user546770 I think you got the wrong discriminant. Note that $(x+2) \geq (x-3)+5 \geq -\sqrt{6}+5$ and $y+1 \leq y-3+4 \leq \sqrt{6}+4$, which means that $k$ is bounded.